# Adobe AIR application is missing the corresponding .xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I am new to Adobe flash builder.
Trying to figure out following error while trying to build a given flex project
"Adobe AIR application is missing the corresponding JWorksApplicationMain-app.xml."

I have set the JWorksApplicationMain.mxml as default in Project-->properties->Flex Applications menu.

As a result of an internet search , I did go to Project-->properties->Flex Applications and look for any reference to .as file however no such references exist.

If would appreciate a solution to this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: The ..-app.xml file is generated when you create a new project in FB. If you dont have one, you'll need to recreate it yourself. see http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=File_formats_1.html

Comment: Easiest approach to create a new one will be to create a new application file in your Flash Builder project; copy the -app file it creates to `JWorksApplicationMain-app.xml` and then delete unused application/-app.xml  files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My peer figured this one out. The issue was that the project in FlashBuilder, the application type set to "Desktop" instead of "Web".

So I deleted the project created a new project with "WEB" application type and now project build with no errors.

Thanks Lee and Reboog711 for your respective inputs.

Thanks,

Comment: no problem. i think you threw us off the scent with the AIR tag :) Thats why we assumed you were creating a desktop app

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by below link

http://www.flexpert.be/2010/04/solving-the-missing-air-application-xml-file-error-in-flash-builder/